# Is it possible to load 32 bits frames using cv::VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read a bunch of `CV_32FC1` frames using cv::VideoCapture, but it loads them like `CV_8UC3` by default.

I tried changing the object properties using `VideoCapture::set()`, but the method keeps returning 0.

**Is it possible to load `CV_32FC1` frames using cv::VideoCapture?** I cannot find the answer in the doc, but I also cannot find a code example.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc , char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture capture;

    // return always 0:
    std::cout << "FORMAT" = " << capture.get( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT ) << std::endl;

    capture("./frames/frame_%02d.BMP";

    // return always 0:
    std::cout << "FORMAT" = " << capture.get( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT ) << std::endl;

    // status is always false
    bool status = capture.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_32FC1 );

    // still 0:
    std::cout << "FORMAT" = " << capture.get( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT ) << std::endl;

    if( !capture.isOpened() )  // isok?
        return -1;

    cv::Mat image;
    capture.read( image );

    // image is 8UC3

    return 0;
}
```

Any comment is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is it possible to load CV_32FC1 frames using cv::VideoCapture?" - no. also, you can't store float images in a .bmp

Comment: Note for future - some properties can be set/get only after grabbing at least 1 or 2 frames from VideoCapture. I know it's strange, but (at least for Windows) that's true.

Comment: @berak, is `CV_16UC1` feasible ?

Comment: I tried with an .avi, without compression. I dont understand why OpenCV is  taking time to read each frame and convert them in 8uc3. They are already in 16uc1, why not keep that ?

Comment: just loop, use imread(filename,-1); don't try to bend the VideoCapture into something it wasn't made for.

Comment: Yep true, I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sait by berak in the comments:

`"Is it possible to load CV_32FC1 frames using cv::VideoCapture?" - no. also, you can't store float images in a .bmp`